# Launch Internet Explorer developer tools with different keyboard shortcut?

Tags: internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

So in Chrome and Firefox, I can launch the inspector with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

I know Internet Explorer uses <kbd>F12</kbd> by default, but those other browsers have had working dev tools for a longer time. IE11 looks much better than previous IE releases (the DOM updates in dev tools without having to click a button all the time) so I'd like to be able to launch the IE dev tools with the same shortcuts.

Comment: BTW IE has had dev tools for at least 6 years now. I am not even sure Chrome existed then...

Comment: @ChrisLove Sure, but as the question mentions, *working* dev tools are a different matter. Having to click a refresh button every time the DOM changes to inspect accurately was ridiculous and IE11 did very well getting rid of it. Even Microsoft's own official IE VMs ship with Firebug lite.

Answer (score 0):

F12 works for Chrome or Firefox too, and it's easier to press for sure. I don't know of a way to remap the keys in IE, but just using F12 is easier.

Comment: What if the website has captured F12 to disable it?